# Connect to remote computer behind firewall by using middle man computer

Tags: vpn, internet

[image: Network Setup]

**The issue:**

- The website will only serve content to `Computer C`
- `Computer A` needs to access the website.
- `Computer A` cannot see `Computer C` and visa-versa
- `Computer B` cannot see `Computer A` and `Computer C`
- However `Computer A` and `Computer C` can see `Computer B`

**The question:**

Is it possible for `Computer A` to see the websites content using `Computer B` as a middle man and routing traffic?

**What I'm thinking so far:**

Both `Computer A` and `Computer C` make a VPN connection to `Computer B` so all computers are sharing a private network. Then `Computer A` sets up a SOCKS PROXY with `Computer C` over the new private network and browses the website through `Computer C`.

Is what I'm thinking going to work? If no, can you provide a solution, if at all? If yes what sort of software would I need to set up and what sort of commands will I need to run to make these connections? All computers Linux but are different distros.

Comment: Do you have access to computer C?  That is the real "middle man."

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot see"?  If Computer B cannot communicate with Computer C then Computer C cannot communicate with Computer B.  At least not with TCP/IP.

Comment: @Ron I have access to all computers providing Im on their private networks. I do not have access to Computer C over the public internet.

Comment: @techie007 when I say `see` I mean cannot connect to it. This is because of the firewall not allowing inbound traffic to computer A or C

Answer (score 2):

First, I am going to assume that what you're asking to do doesn't violate any policies, regulations, laws, etc. That's not the kind of advice I give.

You need to configure relays on B and C.  You can use netcat for this.  It should be on most Linux distros.

On host C, you configure a client-client relay:

```
mknod mypipe p
nc host_B 80 < mypipe | nc web_server 80 | tee mypipe
```

Host C makes an outbound connection to host B on port 80.  Anything it hears in response gets relayed to the webserver. On host B, you configure a listener to listener relay:

```
mknod mypipe p
nc -l -p 8080 < mypipe | nc -l -p 80 | tee mypipe
```

Host B listens on both port 80 and 8080.  Whatever it hears on one port, it will send to the other.

Now, when you browse from Host A to Host B, on port 8080, you should be connected to the web server via Host C.

Comment: Very impressive.  (1) If `mknod` doesn’t work, try `mkfifo`. (2) You might want to use a port other than 80 on Computer B (e.g., 8081) in case (a) there’s already a web server running there, or (b) the user isn’t privileged.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I used port 80 because I assumed it would be open on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can run vpn server on B, but make sure client-to-client communication is enabled. Check Openvpn software, http://www.openvpn.net.

Then configure routing to route traffic from A to Website and back. Check the linux command ip route, http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip.

Another solution would be via 2 GRE tunnels instead of the 2 VPN tunnels above. Check gre tunnels on linux, e.g. http://tier.cs.berkeley.edu/drupal/howto/ip-tunnel-using-gre-on-linux.

I would prefer gre tunnels if the firewalls will pass it through.